# text alignment changing on live server

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am try to add this table on wordpress site but when i adding "p tag" formating remove and its automatically goes to left. When i am testing same code on local machine its working fine. What's Problem with it

```
<style type="text/css">
.tftable {color:#333333;width:100%;border-width: 1px;border-color: #729ea5;border-collapse: collapse; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;table-layout: fixed;}
.tftable th {font-size:24px;background-color:#00D4F3;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;text-align:center;}
.tftable tr {background-color:#D1EFF3;}
.tftable td {font-size:18px;border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #729ea5;}
.tftable tr:hover {background-color:#ffffff;}
.tftable h2 {font-weight:bold; color:0012FF; text-align:center;}
.tftable p {text-align:center;}
</style>

<table class="tftable" border="1">
<tr><th>Wordpress themes</th><th>Theme customization</th><th>Custome Theme</th></tr>
<tr><td>Price</td><td><h2>From $200</h2></td><td><h2>From $400</h2></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Work Delivery Terms</td>
        <td><p>Up to 5 business days</p></td>
        <td><p>from $400</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Theme design and coding</td>
        <td><p>Logo, theme colors, layout is changed according to your preferences. Sub pages css styles of the theme are edited according to the theme style.</p></td>
        <td><p>Custom, unique homepage and up to 10 sub pages designed and coded. Psd design mockup is provided only for the homepage.</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Plugins installation/design</td>
        <td><p>Up to 3 plugins installation and setup.</p></td>
        <td><p>Up to 5 plugins installation, setup and style change according to the theme.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Additional plugins installation/design</td>
        <td><p>$30 per hour</p></td>
        <td><p>$30 per hour</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Slider on the Home Page</td>
        <td><p>$35</p></td>
        <td><p>Included</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Logo</td>
        <td><p>Simple non-vector logo (1 concept)</p></td>
        <td><p>Simple non-vector logo (max 2 concepts</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Additinal pages design/coding</td>
        <td><p>$30 per hour</p></td>
        <td><p>$30 per hour</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Footer backlink removal fee</p></td>
        <td><p>$30</td>
        <td><p>$30</p></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Are you trying to paste the `<style>` element into WP's HTML editor?

Comment: no I have added my css coding in theme css file. and when i am saving my code <p> tag automatically remove. https://www.grownstar.biz/web-template-pricing/

Comment: get it that if i use text alignment in <td> tag than it would be posible. but i still want to know why <p> tag is removing in wordpress editor.

Comment: Weird. I just tried, but if I try the same, the `<p>` remains in place in the `<td>`. Sorry I can't help you.

Comment: see this wordpress remove <p> tag . got my all answers now . thanks
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/editor-removes-p-tags